# Return all the possible combinations in the dictionary where the value is equal to the corresponding key (JAVA)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iterator, combinations

Given a schedule order `["delivery", "service", "application"]`

Given eligible clients for each

```
"delivery" -> "food", "drink"
"service" -> "taxi", "motor-bike"
"application" -> "mobile-device"
```

Give list of schedule
Option 1: delivery: food, service: taxi, application: mobile-device
Option 2: delivery: drink, service: taxi, application: mobile-device
Option 3: delivery: food, service: motor-bike, application: mobile-device
Option 4: delivery: drink, service: motor-bike, application: mobile-device

Return all the possible combinations that the value equals to their corresponding key.

My approach:

```
public String delivery() {
   List<String> key = List.of("delivery", "service", "application");
   Map<String, List<String>> value = Map.of("delivery", List.of("food", "drink"),
                                            "service", List.of("taxi", "motor-bike"),
                                            "application", List.of("mobile-device"));
  HashMap mapCombination = new HashMap<>();
mapCombination.put("delivery", new String[] {"food", "drink"});
mapCombination.put("service", new String[] {"taxi", "motor-bike"});
mapCombination.put("application", new String[] {"mobile-device"});

 for(String key: value) {
     key.hasNext();
}
```

My plan is to have a HashMap, since a map has a key-value pair where it put in the key value pair. There it will iterate over the for loop to check if there is a next value assuming the list is not empty. It will keep iterate and update to print out all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem, you're trying to get a `List` containing all the possible combinations of the input map, where each combination (or option) contains every key paired with only one of the values of their corresponding list.

Personally, I would tackle this problem by using recursion where each recursive step works on a specific key. On each recursive call, the list of values of the current key is traversed and the `i-th` value is added to a temporary `Map` to create a possible option. Once a stack of recursive calls ends, it means that there are no further keys to visit and that an option has been built.

Basically, the whole core lies within the for loop, where each key continues to populate an option from the previous key's `i-th` value.

```
public static void getCombinations(Map<String, List<String>> mapInput, List<Map<String, String>> listRes) {
    getCombinationsHelper(mapInput, listRes, new HashMap<>(), new ArrayList<>(mapInput.keySet()), 0);
}

private static void getCombinationsHelper(Map<String, List<String>> mapInput, List<Map<String, String>> listRes, Map<String, String> mapOption, List<String> keys, int keyIndex) {
    //Base case where there are no further keys, so the option is complete and it can be added to the resulting list
    if (keyIndex == keys.size()) {
        listRes.add(new HashMap<>(mapOption));
        return;
    }

    //Traversing the key's values
    List<String> value = mapInput.get(keys.get(keyIndex));
    for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
        //Adding the key's i-th value into the option
        mapOption.put(keys.get(keyIndex), value.get(i));

        //Moving to the next key to populate the option
        getCombinationsHelper(mapInput, listRes, mapOption, keys, keyIndex + 1);

        //Removing the key's i-th value to create another combination with the next value
        mapOption.remove(keys.get(keyIndex));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> mapValues = Map.of(
            "delivery", List.of("food", "drink"),
            "service", List.of("taxi", "motor-bike"),
            "application", List.of("mobile-device")
    );

    List<Map<String, String>> listCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
    getCombinations(mapValues, listCombinations);

    for (Map<String, String> map : listCombinations) {
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
{delivery=food, application=mobile-device, service=taxi}
{delivery=food, application=mobile-device, service=motor-bike}
{delivery=drink, application=mobile-device, service=taxi}
{delivery=drink, application=mobile-device, service=motor-bike}
```

Here is a link to test the code:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rSO

Comment: So the time and space complexity here can be O(n) because it recursively call to find the possible combinations

Comment: @engicode123 if n is the number of keys and m the average number of elements within the lists then the complexity is O(n x m). However, you're traversing each element only once and since you have to build every possible combination, you're just iterating every element the minimum number of times